# git blame - ignore uncommitted changes

Tags: git, blame

Partial output from `git blame <file>`:

```
    ...
   d6182477 (<author>          2012-06-22 09:44:02 -0400 239) ...
   d6182477 (<author>          2012-06-22 09:44:02 -0400 240) ...
   25f98f3f (<author>          2012-06-15 15:44:00 -0400 245) ...
   25f98f3f (<author>          2012-06-15 15:44:00 -0400 246) ...
   35853aa2 (<author>          2012-06-22 08:12:41 -0400 247) ...
   25f98f3f (<author>          2012-06-15 15:44:00 -0400 248) ...
-> 00000000 (Not Committed Yet 2012-06-27 08:33:35 -0400 249) ...
-> 00000000 (Not Committed Yet 2012-06-27 08:33:35 -0400 249) ...
   25f98f3f (<author>          2012-06-15 15:44:00 -0400 250) ...
   35853aa2 (<author>          2012-06-22 08:12:41 -0400 251) ...
   25f98f3f (<author>          2012-06-15 15:44:00 -0400 252) ...
    ...
```

How does one get `git blame` to ignore uncommitted changes from the file?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
git blame HEAD <file>
```

From the `git blame` manual:

> Annotates each line in the given file with information from the
>   revision which last modified the line. **Optionally, start annotating
>   from the given revision.**